# if function in R like Excel

Tags: r

I want if function in like use in Excel, eg:

```
=IF((RIGHT(A1,7)+1)=(RIGHT(A2,7)+0),"Correct Invoice Number","Repeated")
```

(what i did in my excel formula, first of all i take 07 digit from right in cell, afterr that i add +1 in same, and compare to next value which is next cell right 07 digit's, like 1+1=2, and next value is 2 then it is ok but if 1+1=2 and next value is 3 then it is false)

Here I mention `A1` and `A2` is cell reference...

My data like..
         A
1   SERIAL/1000146
2   SERIAL/1000147
3   SERIAL/1000147
4   SERIAL/1000149
6   SERIAL/1000150
7   SERIAL/1000151
8   SERIAL/1000151
9   SERIAL/1000153
10  SERIAL/1000154
11  SERIAL/1000155
12  SERIAL/1000156
13  SERIAL/1000157
14  SERIAL/1000158

I use above formula in Excel, like if next value in repeated to next then it will identify .

Comment: Read about lead lag functions.

Answer (score 2):

please, read the manual:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/ifelse

`ifelse` function seems to match the functionality you're looking for